# How to get applictionid in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

i mistakenly deleted my applicationId in build.gradle (Module:app)
in my android studio project.
is there any way for me to reset it?
i cannot run or debug or rebuild my project .
please help,I'm stuck.

Comment: just Rewrite it in gradle like this   applicationId "abc.com.mobile"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio saves the history of all your file changes. Open you `build.gradle` file, go to Menu `VCS` -> `Local History` -> `Show History`. You can also revert automatically to previous versions by selecting a version in the left pane, right click and select `Revert`.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it in gradle like this..

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abc.com.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

If App is already Published and then go to app link and in link after id= is your pakage name as in this link ez.intandif.iniplayer is pakage name. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ez.intandif.iniplayer